# Track progress of IO.copy_stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm downloading a file from a URL:

```
url = "https://aws-file-url.com/bucket/large-file.mov"
path = Rails.root.join("tmp", SecureRandom.hex(12).to_s + Time.now.to_i.to_s)
IO.copy_stream(url, path)
```

Downloading the file using `IO.copy_stream` takes time, and I'd like to be able to track the amount already downloaded and have the total amount to download so I can get a percentage or something equivalent.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: According to the documentation, there's no progress indicator / callback.

Comment: Not a full answer, but if you know how long the source stream is, you could wrap the IO object and have it do a progress callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OpenURI::OpenRead](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html). Its open() method has two lambdas, :content_length_proc and :progress_proc that provides exactly what you ask for.

For instance, if you'd like a progress bar:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'progressbar' # you must install: gem install progressbar

pbar = nil
open(url,
   :content_length_proc => lambda { |t|
      if t && 0 < t
         pbar = ProgressBar.create(
            title: "Some download title for progress bar",
            total:t,
            progress_mark:'█'.encode('utf-8')
         )
      end
    },

    :progress_proc => lambda {|s|
       pbar.progress = s if pbar
    }
) { |f|
  IO.copy_stream(f, path)
}
```

Notice that there is no error handling at this code.

I hope it solves your problem!